# Video stabiilisation using "Warp Stabiliser"

Tags: video

I recently shot some very shaky video footage using my DSLR camera.

http://vid1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah44/hellocatfood/MVI_3154_zps6fri0edh.mp4

I usually use a tripod for stability but the situation meant I did not have one available to me. Whilst searching for ways to stabilise the video I came across [various tutorials](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/329-ubuntu-trusty-rotate-stabilize-video-melt-vidstab) that reference using either vid.stab and/or kdenlive/MLT. The results it produced were a bit odd.

http://vid1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah44/hellocatfood/MVI_3154-stab_zpsbbqnr0qm.mp4

I used the following settings

[image]

For comparison I asked a friend to stabilise the same video using the [Warp Stabiliser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MW3qU6pXBtA) found in Adobe Premier Pro.

http://vid1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah44/hellocatfood/Stabilised%20MVI_3154_zps4e3obbot.mp4

They used the following settings
[[image]]

The artefacts I noted are similar to what is described [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MW3qU6pXBtA). The video, when stabilised using vid.stab appears a bit warped. I appreciate that no software will produce an incredibly smooth video but I am left wondering, is there any open source software, GUI or command-line, available for Ubuntu/Linux that can effectively stabilise video using a process similar to the Warp Stabiliser found in Adobe Premier Pro?